# Генерация случайного вогнутого многогранника (Java)

Tags: java, разработка-игр, графика, дискретная-математика

Всем доброго времени суток! Придумал заняться изучением Java и стало интересно создать генерируемый по точкам огонь в окошке. И все бы ничего, да сижу уже долго а придумать как собирать правильный массив точек не могу.

Итак имеется:

- массив точек, динамически изменяющих своё положение;
- функция отрисовки полилинии по массиву точек.

Однако, в силу того, что точки генерируются рандомно, линия проходит не по внешнему краю из точек, а следует по порядку их появления.

[image: 1]

Так выглядит полилиния, которая отрисовывается по порядку точек в начальном массиве: ***(2й-фрейм)***.

То, что я пытался сделать сейчас, должно бы выглядеть примерно так: ***(3й-фрейм)***.

Тогда после можно будет уже добавлять физику горения огня и другие приятные эффекты, однако я застрял, т.к. никак не могу собрать массив нужного вида (формы).

```
polyX = new double[Pannel.hights.size()];
polyY = new double[Pannel.hights.size()];
dist = new double[Pannel.hights.size()][Pannel.hights.size()];

for(int i = 0; i < dist.length; i++) {
    for(int p = 0; p < dist.length; p++) {
        double ndistB =
            Math.abs(Pannel.hights.get(i).getX() -
            Pannel.hights.get(p).getX()) +
            Math.abs(Pannel.hights.get(i).getY() -
            Pannel.hights.get(p).getY());

     // Distance
        dist[i][p] = ndistB;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < polyX.length; i++) {
    int pB = 0;
    for (int p = 0; p < polyX.length; p++) {
        if (distB > dist[i][p] && i != p && dist[i][p] != -1) {
            distB = dist[i][p];
            pB = p; // pBuffer
        }
    }
    polyX[i] = Pannel.hights.get(pB).getX();
    polyY[i] = Pannel.hights.get(pB).getY();
}
distB = 300;
```

Где

- `Pannel.hights.get(i).getX()` и `.getY()` отвечают за координаты в основном классе вершин;
- `dis[i][p]` — дистанция от i-ой до p-ой точки;
- `polyX` и `polyY` — массивы координат, которые я заполняю, чтобы после передать на отрисовку новой полилинии.

Пытался реализовать поиск ближайшей вершины (определение расстояний между вершинами), однако получалось нечто вроде этого: ***(4й-фрейм)***.

В теории — должно бы получиться что-то не сильно полезное, но весьма занятное (из серии точки "спавна" воды/огня/различных материалов).
Буду благодарен за подсказки или предложения, т.к. сам вряд ли справлюсь :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создавать точки в радиальных координатах и после строить радиальную диаграмму. Получаются очень неплохие многоугольники без самопересечения. Картинка примера из excel.

[image: Смоделировал в excel.]

Answer (score 0):

По сути то, что у вас показано на третьем изображении, реализуется взятием:

- 3+x левых крайних точек;
- 3+x верхних крайних точек;
- 3+x правых крайних точек;
- 3+x нижних крайних точек.

...полученные в итоге 12 точек соединяем в фигуру, и заливаем (x — будет здесь означать глубину/сложность фигуры).

Comment: Так-то, то что ты предлагаешь - не плохо, но вопрос следующий - в каком порядке соединять точки в фигуру? В плане - в каком порядке записывать их координаты в массив, по которому идет отрисовка фигуры?

Comment: по часовой стрелке бери и в массив кидай - левый край точки с нижней по вернхнюю, верхний край с лева на право точки в массив и так далее...